# MAME emulator for Mac?

Tags: macos

Everybody knows [MAME](http://mamedev.org/). 
I wonder where can I find an updated Mac version (if possible with a GUI) of Mame.

I've found SDL Mame that looks promising (no GUI however), but I'm not able to download it from [the official site](http://sdlmame.lngn.net/).

Do you have any alternative or a mirror?

Comment: No gui, but current builds of mame for os x available here: http://sdlmame.lngn.net

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[OpenEmu](http://www.openemu.org)

[image]

Hands down the most beautiful, elegant and functional emulator to ever grace OS X. The initial public release was loosed on December 25, 2013.

If you'd like a version that has MAME support (among other consoles not included in vanilla download), click the arrow and choose the experimental version.

[image]

Then simply install the MAME core, drag your ROMs to the Arcade window, and OpenEmu will do the rest.

[image]

Lastly, for discussions on the topic, [see this thread](https://github.com/OpenEmu/OpenEmu/pull/666) on github.

Comment: * nice, looks like compiling from source is not the only option now :)

Comment: @Napolux You are welcome. If at any time you'd like to try SDL MAME, you can find v0.149 here: http://mac.majorgeeks.com/files/details/sdlmame.html (it also provides a link to the SDL runtime libraries, which you'll need). However, it is not at all as user friendly (or has such a pretty UI) as OpenEmu.

Comment: I tried SDL Mame, but I was searching for a more "MAC" experience. OpenEmu is definitely my choice.

Comment: OpenEmu seem to like 10.10/10.11. Hangs a lot shortly after startup.

Answer (score 2):

Try MAME OS X:

**http://mameosx.sourceforge.net/**

[image]

• [MAMEOSX 0.135](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mameosx/MAMEOSX-0.135.dmg?download) — 24 MB .dmg containing compiled version (GUI)

• [source code](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mameosx/mameosx-0.135.tgz?download) - 14 MB .tgz containing uncompiled source

---

Another option is [OpenEmu](http://www.openemu.org/) (which uses Modules), The latest version is quite nice looking, and is [available here](http://www.openemu.org/), or you can compile it from source, [available here](https://github.com/OpenEmu/OpenEmu/wiki/Compiling-From-Source-Guide).

Answer (score 1):

I currently use [MAME Launcher](http://nekocanmac.seesaa.net/) as a frontend for [SDLMAME](http://sdlmame.lngn.net/), [MAME OS X](http://mameosx.sourceforge.net/) or [MacMAME](http://www.macmame.org/). If you use SDLMAME, along with the binary, don't forget to install the SDL Runtime Library in `~/Library/Frameworks`. Then just set the correct paths in MAME Launcher.

The reason I use MAME Launcher (and SDLMAME) is because I can play a ROM (eg. `ddragon.zip`) simply by double-clicking on it, after setting it to open with MAME Launcher via Finder's/Path Finder's Get Info. Or even quicker, just by browsing my `Games/Arcade` folder in LaunchBar and press enter to run a game. Since SDLMAME is just a binary, MAME Launcher will open but will run the game immediately.
If you prefer, you can use MAME Launcher as a frontend and browse/launch your ROMS from there, if you like the extra options such as screenshots, flyers, info, search, etc.

[MAME Launcher v3.2 Mirror Link](http://microvoid.in/repo/public/app/mame-launcher/) - In case the official website goes down.

[MAME Launcher http://microvoid.in/repo/public/app/mame-launcher/mame-launcher.png](http://microvoid.in/repo/public/app/mame-launcher/mame-launcher.png)

Comment: Every attempt I have made to use MAME OS X has failed with the system complaining about missing files. Oddly the files that it lists as missing seem to have reasonable names, but I can find no trace of them in the actual files.

Comment: MAME OS X was lastly updated in 2009 but it shouldn't complain about missing files. As far as I remember, it didn't need the SDL framework as it's a self-contained app bundle. Are you sure it's not the games you're trying to run that are missing files? In that case you need to look for better ROMs.

Comment: It is not complaining about files *in the emulator*, it is complaining that the ROMs themselves are bad. I have tried ROMs from multiple sources with the same outcomes. Do you have it working mega? If so, could you point me to an URL for, say, the original asteroids that works on your version? Then I'll try that source.

Comment: I don't have Asteroids but remember there are game ROMs (the actual game images) and BIOS ROMs (BIOS dumps necessary for some games to load correctly). Try to search Emuparadise for "Asteroids" and "BIOS pack".

Comment: No joy. Just downloaded fresh copies. Now I don't get the missing files error, I simply get a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

I try [SDL MAME Emulator](https://www.retrostic.com/emulators/mame/sdl-mame) for my MAC OS PC and it ok for the demanding that I want for playing MAME Games. I had the first time problem while the game loaded every time occurs error about " change the SDL settings" I download a BIOS file that should help me but no the error still appears. And suddenly I found out that the game name and Winrar name should be the same or the game wouldn't play and extracting of the files wasn't needed. After fixing that problem the real joy starts by playing lots of MAME games like I was young and after work the kids days where back.